# Is stringstream better than string's operator '+' for string objects concatenation?

Tags: c++, string

For example, I have two string objects:string str_1, str_2. I want to concatenate to them. I can use two methods:
method 1:

```
std::stringstream ss;
//std::string str_1("hello");
//std::string str_2("world");
ss << "hello"<< "world"；
const std::string dst_str = std::move(ss.str());
```

method 2:

```
std::string str_1("hello");
std::string str_2("world");
const std::string dst_str = str_1 + str_2;
```

Because the string's buffer is read only, when you change the string object, its buffer will destroy and create a new one to store new content. So method 1 is better than method 2? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The answer is obvious (i.e., method #2). You avoid the creation of a `stringstream` plus the two insertions plus the call to `.str()`.

Comment: @cwfighter Did you try to profile the two options?

Comment: C++ != C# or Java. C++ strings are not immutable.

Comment: Can you define "better"?

Comment: @AmiTavory Sorry, I have not wrote some test codes to verify it. I think destroy old and create a new buffer take more time.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı "better" means that it will take less time.

Comment: @cwfighter Why don't you consider aspects such as readibility, error checking?

Comment: This question comes off as somewhat lazy. It is very easy to test which is faster: run each version 10,000x in a loop and measure how long it takes. Then you could ask why and present your understanding of the problem, which would make much more sense.

Comment: ***"better" means that it will take less time.*** I do not think the difference in time would be that much so it may be difficult to get an accurate benchmark unless you append several thousand strings instead of just 2.

Comment: The `std::move` in your #1 is useless, `ss.str()` already returns an rvalue that can be moved. Also, _"Because the string's buffer is read only"_ is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks, my  `std:move()` is useless, because string object define move operator '='. But string's buffer is absolutely read-only, it is a `const char*`

Comment: @cwfighter, wow, so much wrong. You're not using string's `operator=` you're using its constructor. And internally strings have a modifiable buffer, they just return `const char*` from `c_str()`. If they were not modifiable how do you think `std::string s = "foo"; s[0] = 'w';` would work?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Maybe you have not knew it well. Your example is easy to mislead. `string.c_str()` will get a `const char*` not a `char*`, only if  `(char*)string.c_str()`, so I think the operation `s[0] = 'w'` will destroy and create a new one. I hanve a example: `std::string s = "hello", s = "hello world"`, it will destroy and create a new one. OK?

Comment: @cwfighter, trust me, I know `std::string` well. _" I think the operation `s[0] = 'w'` will destroy and create a new one."_ You may think that, but you are wrong, see http://ideone.com/xQTLpk which proves that you don't get a new string, you edit the existing one. Even your other example is not guaranteed to create a new string, it depends whether `s` has enough capacity for the new contents. You are making incorrect assumptions and stating them as fact.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You can test my example, the `(void*)string.c_str()` will changed, but the  `(void*)string.c_str()`  in example you gave did not changed. Now I am more and more confused. Thank you for your example.

Comment: @cwfighter, it's really quite simple. The contents of a `std::string` **are not read-only** (like I said all along!). So updating an existing character in a string doesn't need to create a new string, it just changes one character. So for my example a new string is never created, and this is guaranteed by the standard. Replacing the string contents with a new string _sometimes_ creates a new string, if the capacity is not large enough to hold the new contents. For your example it depends on the implementation of `std::string` whether a new string is created or not.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks a lot ! Now I see it. Your explanation is simple and clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`stringstreams` are complex objects compared to simple strings.  Everythime you use method 1,  a `stringstream` must be constructed, and later destructed.  If you do this millions of time, the overhead will be far from neglectible.

The apparently simple `ss << str_1 << str_2` is in fact equivalent to `std::operator<<(sst::operator<<(ss, str_1), str_2);` which is not optimized for in memory concatenation, but common to all the [streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3C%3C/).

I've done a small benchmark :

- in debug mode, method 2 is almost twice as fast as method1.
- In optimized build (verifying in the assembler file that nothing was optimized away), it's more then 27 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for yous help. My test is same as your answer.

Comment: @DawidDrozd Because the narrative explains why it will be faster in any situation. The difference in debug shows only the effect effect that corresponds to the explanation, whereas the optimized version adds other improvements on top.

Answer (score 2):

Thans for everyone. Maybe I was a little lazy. Now I gave the code test.

test 1: 158.751ms, so long, my god!

```
    int main()
    {
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            //string str_1("hello ");
            //string str_2("world");
            stringstream ss;
            ss << "hello " << "world";
            const string dst_str = ss.str();
        }
        chrono:: high_resolution_clock::time_point stop_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        chrono::duration<double> slapsed = duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop_time - begin_time);
        cout << "time takes " << slapsed.count() * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

test 2: 31.1946ms, fastest!

```
    int main()
    {
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            string str_1("hello ");
            string str_2("world");
            const string dst_str = str_1 + str_2;
        }
        chrono:: high_resolution_clock::time_point stop_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        chrono::duration<double> slapsed = duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop_time - begin_time);
        cout << "time takes " << slapsed.count() * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

test 3: use boost::filesystem::path 35.1769ms, also a nice choice

```
    int main()
    {
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            string str_1("hello ");
            string str_2("world");
            boost::filesystem::path dst_path(str_1);
            dst_path += str_2;
            const string dst = dst_path.string();
        }
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point stop_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        chrono::duration<double> slapsed = duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop_time - begin_time);
        cout << "time takes " << slapsed.count() * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
        return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Method 2 is better as your situation here. Since it has better readability and time cost less for declining the stringstream obj creation.
- But, I strongly recommend to use format for better readability & maintenance, instead of "+" or other string concatenation.