# Encrypting a string but receiving an infinite loop

Tags: c++

### Problem:

I was trying to encrypt a `std::string` password with a single rule:

- **Add "0" before and after a vowel**

So that `bAnanASplit` becomes `b0A0n0a0n0A0Spl0i0t`.
However, I got stuck in an infinite loop.

### Here is the code:

```cpp
    const std::string VOWELS = "AEIOUaeiou";
    std::string pass = "bAnanASplit";

    //Add zeroes before and after vowels
    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); ++i)
    {
        i = pass.find_first_of(VOWELS, i);
        std::cout << pass << "\n";
        if(i != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << pass[i] << ": " << i << "\n";
            pass.insert(pass.begin() + i++, '0');
            pass.insert(pass.begin() + ++i, '0');
        }
    }
```

### ...And the result:

```
bAnanASplit
A: 1
b0A0nanASplit
a: 5
b0A0n0a0nASplit
A: 9
b0A0n0a0n0A0Split
i: 15
b0A0n0a0n0A0Spl0i0t
b0A0n0a0n0A0Spl0i0t
A: 2
b00A00n0a0n0A0Spl0i0t
a: 8
b00A00n00a00n0A0Spl0i0t
A: 14
b00A00n00a00n00A00Spl0i0t
i: 22
b00A00n00a00n00A00Spl00i00t
b00A00n00a00n00A00Spl00i00t
...
```

Any help? This sure seems strange.

**Edit:** All the answers were useful, and therefore I have accepted the one which I think best answers the question. However, the best way to solve the problem is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59235998/9414470) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP seems to look for the exact reason for the misbehavior, I thought to add another answer as the existing answers do not show the exact issue.

The reason for the unexpected behavior is visible in following lines.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); ++i)
{
    i = pass.find_first_of(VOWELS, i);
    ...
```

Problem 1:

The loop counter `i` is an `int` (i.e. a `signed int`). But [std::string::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) returns [std::string::npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) if there's no match. This is usually the maximum number representable by an `unsigned long`. Assigning a huge `unsigned` value to a shorter `signed` variable will store a totally unexpected value (assuming you are not aware of that). In this case, `i` will becomes `-1` in most platforms (try `int k = std::string::npos;` and print `k` if you need to be sure). `i = -1` is valid state for the loop condition `i < pass.length()`, so the next iteration will be allowed.

Problem 2:

Closely related to the above problem, same variable `i` is used to define the start position for the `find` operation. But, as explained, `i` will not represent the index of the character as you would expect.

Solution:

Storing a malformed value can be solved by using the proper data type. In the current scenario, best options would be using `std::string::size_type` as this is always guaranteed to work (most probably this will be equal to `size_t` everywhere). To make the program work with the given logic, you will also have to use a different variable to store the `find` result.

However, a better solution would be using a `std::stringstream` for building the string. This will perform better than modifying a string by inserting characters in the middle.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    const string VOWELS = "AEIOUaeiou";
    const string pass = "bAnanASplit";

    stringstream ss;

    for (const char pas : pass) {
        if (VOWELS.find(pas) == std::string::npos) {
            ss << pas;
        } else {
            ss << '0' << pas << '0';
        }
    }
    cout << pass << "\n";
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Comment: An interesting addition would be the [comparision between `stringstream <<` and `string +=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254175/is-stringstream-better-than-strings-operator-for-string-objects-concatenati) when doing a lot of computations...

Comment: Yes, I think direct string concatenation will be better than using `stringstream` as the generated string won't be very long. However a significant performance difference won't be noticed (in that case, in any of the 3 ways discussed here) unless you do this repeatedly for a large number of times.

Answer (score 5):

**Never, ever, modify the collection/container you are iterating upon!**

Saves you a lot of trouble that way.

Let's start with your code and generate a new string with vowels surrounded by `0`.

```
const std::string VOWELS = "AEIOUaeiou";
std::string pass = "bAnanASplit", replacement;

//Add zeroes before and after vowels
for (auto ch : pass)
{
    if(VOWELS.find(ch) != std::string::npos)
        replacement += '0' + ch + '0';
    else
        replacement += ch;
}
```

And there you have it!

Comment: "never ever ..." is a wrong claim in general. In fact, you can modify a container while being iterated as long as you guarantee the used iterator is correctly updated at the end of each iteration.

Comment: While you are right of course, and your way is better, the other answer answers the actual question. You can still add that part, so that the whole answer is in 1 place. +1 nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

You are not exiting the loop in case `i` becomes `std::string::npos`. So, the `i` value is changed to some unexpected value (likely something like -1) when it gets to the position of last i or 0 after i(here I am referring to i of spl**i**t). This is because `i` is an signed integer but in this case `find_first_of()` returns `std::string::npos` which is largest value that can be held by a `size_t`. In that case the terminating condition `i < pass.length()` may hold true and the loop continues. So, I am recommending following changes in your code -

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < pass.length(); ++i)
{
    i = pass.find_first_of(VOWELS, i);
    if(i == std::string::npos)
        break;

    pass.insert(pass.begin() + i++, '0');
    pass.insert(pass.begin() + ++i, '0');
}
```

On the same note `if (i != std::String::npos)` does not do what you are expecting it to do.

But then again it better not to modify the container while you are iterating over it which @Tanveer mentioned in his answer

Comment: "... the i value is never changed when it gets to the position of last i" why? Can you please clarify this point?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar, sorry it does changes and becomes std::string::npos. But npos is unsigned value and you are storing it an integer, so it becomes -1 and it starts from the beginning of the string

Comment: While this answer answers my question, the other tells us a better way to solve it. Arghh, the dilemma you guys are posing... :-)

Comment: @JaideepShekhar, if Tanveer's answer works for you, choose it as the answer. I just hope my answer is able to point out the error in your code. :)